# Change and update values in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am working with a bigger dataframe of which I need to select a time interval, modify the values and update them in this dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'datetime': ['2020-09-01T00:15:00.000000000', '2020-09-01T00:30:00.000000000',
       '2020-09-01T00:45:00.000000000', ...,
       '2020-09-30T23:30:00.000000000', '2020-09-30T23:45:00.000000000',
       '2020-10-01T00:00:00.000000000'],
                          'p': [407.4 , 410.76, 411.6 , ..., 478.8 , 456.12, 451.08],
                          'q': [47.88, 52.08, 53.76, ..., 77.28, 68.04, 63.84]})
```

For that I selected the desired interval from the function `pd.between_time` ,modified the values and stored them in a smaller dataframe.:

```
df1 = (df.between_time(start_time='07:15:00',end_time='17:00:00')).reset_index()
```

Now I would like to "paste" these values into my larger dataframe. How could I do that? I tested the functions `pd.uptade`, `pd.merge`, `pd.join` but I must be applying them incorrectly because there was loss of information:

```
df.update(df1)
```

Comment: Maybe `df.set_index('datetime').update(df1.set_index('datetime'))`?

Comment: I've  tried, but then my changes to the values of the p and q columns were not applied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you can use np.where to update the values ?
For example, I create new column, but you can overwrite old one:

```
df.datetime = pd.to_datetime(df.datetime)
df.set_index('datetime', inplace = True)


df['new_p'] = np.where(df.index.isin(df.between_time(start_time='00:15:00',end_time='00:30:00').index), 99999, df['p'])
```

Output: 
[image]

Comment: Thank you, i used the modified values as a list and that solve my problem